# Dissolve a corporation as a minor stakeholder in New York

Tags: united-states, corporate-law, new-york-state, new-york-city

I am a minor shareholder (control less than 20% of the shares) at a startup that never did any business. It is a C-Corp incorporated in New York under my name. Right now I want to dissolve the corporation, but I cannot locate one of the stakeholders who controls a significant part of the corporation.

I then read an article on [smallbusiness.chron.com](http://smallbusiness.chron.com) which I cannot find anymore. The article suggests that dissolving the corporation only requires to form a majority to vote on dissolution. However, according to the New York State [Certificate of Dissolution](https://www.dos.ny.gov/forms/corporations/1337-f.pdf), dissolution can only be done after one of the following conditions is met:

- The dissolution was authorized at a meeting of shareholders by
  two-thirds of the votes of all outstanding shares entitled to vote.
- The dissolution was authorized at a meeting of shareholders by a
  majority of the votes of all outstanding shares entitled to vote.
- The dissolution was authorized by the unanimous written consent of the
  holders of all outstanding shares entitled to vote without a meeting.

To my understanding, that implies that I have to have a meeting with all of the shareholders, which is difficult since the difference in geographical locations. Also the corporation has some unallocated shares. So can I still simply form a majority to dissolve the corporation?

Comment: NY law allows board meetings to be carried out through teleconference facilities.  The same may be true of shareholder meetings.

Comment: @phoog Any reference?

Comment: I don't have it handy but I can look it up tomorrow.

Comment: Usually, the corporation will be administratively dissolved if it does not maintain its regular corporate reports to the Secretary of State and pay the fees associated with that. Also, note that, until dissolved, a federal tax return must be filed each year.

Comment: It's at [Business Corporation Law section 708, Action by the Board](http://codes.findlaw.com/ny/business-corporation-law/bsc-sect-708.html).  It authorizes participation by conference call "unless otherwise restricted by the certificate of incorporation or the by-laws."  That section is part of *Article 7, Directors and Officers.*  I did not see similar language in *Article 6, Shareholders,* but I didn't look very thoroughly.